# Private backing field for entity framework lazy loading

Tags: c#, lazy-loading, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5 with lazy loading enabled. I have got the following code:

```
    private ICollection<Subscription> _subscriptions = new Collection<Subscription>();

    public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions
    {
        get { return _subscriptions; }
        set { _subscriptions = value; }
    }
```

But does this make sense? I want to ensure that the public property `Subscriptions` is never null. Due to the virtual entity framework overrides the getter and setter to provide the lazy loading functionality.

Do I need this field or can I just use an auto property and I get an empty list if there is no Subscription?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code will work if the object is constructed via the *new* keyword.  Note however that [many serializers function such that object constructors and field initializers do not work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9419743/141172).

I have settled on the following pattern for that reason:

```
private ICollection<Subscription> _subscriptions;

public virtual ICollection<Subscription> Subscriptions
{
    get 
    {   
        if (_subscriptions == null) _subscriptions = 
            new Collection<Subscription>();

        return _subscriptions; 
    }
    set { _subscriptions = value; }
}
```

This code pattern works with EF, and works whether the object is instantiated with *new* or with a serializer that doesn't run the object's initialization code.

The *get* can also be more compactly written using the null-coalescing operator:

```
    get 
    {   
        return _subscriptions ?? (_subscriptions = 
            new Collection<Subscription>()); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! Your getter can be: `return _subscriptions ?? (_subscriptions = new Collection<Subscription>());`. It's a bit shorter :)