# How do I to add object collection to an object variable collection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, nested, nullreferenceexception

I have a nested collection in side an object:

```
public class Question
{   
    public AnswerObjectCollection Answers
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

When I try to add answers to the `AnswerObjectCollection` in the `Question` object I get following exception:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

```
Question currQuestion = new Question();
currQuestion.Answers.AddRange(GetAnswersByQuestion(currQuestion.QuestionIdentity));
```

If I try to create the answer object first (which does work) I can't add that either

```
AnswerObjectCollection answer = new AnswerObjectCollection();
answer.AddRange(GetAnswersByQuestion(currQuestion.QuestionIdentity));
currQuestion.Answers.AddRange(answer);
```

If I try mapping the objects I don't get an error but the `currQuestion.Answers` variable is null

```
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(AnswerObjectCollection), typeof(AnswerObjectCollection));
Mapper.CreateMap(typeof(Answer), typeof(Answer));
Mapper.Map(answer, currQuestion.Answers);
```

Comment: Please mark an answer as solved, if one helped you solving your problem.

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a constructor to your `Question` class

```
public class Question {
    public Question() {
       Answers = new AnswerObjectCollection();
    }
    public AnswerObjectCollection Answers {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

This will instantiate your `Answers` property.

Comment: Note that a constructor is not always invoked, for example when deserializing an object using some of the framework's serializers.

Comment: @EricJ. I think if you specify a parameter-less constructor, it will be called when instantiating an instance. I'll have to verify tho ;)

Comment: @EricJ: I have deserialised a lot  and I haven't encountered a problem before. But maybe I was just 'lucky' :) . I'll go do some research on this. Thanks for pointing out a possible problem.

Comment: Here's the problem http://stackoverflow.com/q/9419743/141172

Comment: @EricJ: I tested the code using JSON de/serialising and the constructor is triggered. I do not know if it works for all de/serialisers though. From your link, it looks like it might simply depend on the de/serialiser that is being used.

Comment: Some but not all serializers opt not to fully construct the object.  Not sure about the JSON serializer.

Comment: @robbins: NP:)  I recommend testing it when de/serialising, to ensure the constructor is being hit.

Answer (score 0):

Easy as this:

After creating a `Question` by calling

```
Question currQuestion = new Question();
```

you have to create an instance of the `AnswerObjectCollection`

```
currQuestion.Answers = new AnswerObjectCollection();
```

and it will work.

Or add this to your code:

```
public Question()
{
    Answers = new AnswerObjectCollection();
}
```

Comment: Note that a constructor is not always invoked, for example when deserializing an object using some of the framework's serializers.

Comment: @EricJ. that#s true, but I think this might be ok, if he invokes it before.

Comment: It's probably fine for this application, but it's a surprising and *potentially* important fact so I wanted to point it out.

Comment: @EricJ. you're right (and allowed, what's the purpose of `SO`) to do so, please go on this way! New c# users might be grateful for your comment, when having this problem!

Comment: @cramopy - thanks for you quick, and clear response, I used your second suggestion.

Comment: @robbins thanks a lot, if if helped you please tick my answer as accepted :D thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The property `Answers` is not being initialized. You need to do this when constructing the class `Question`,

```
public Question()
{
    Answers = new AnswerObjectCollection();
}
```

By default, all properties and field will be initialized to a default value (`default(T)`). For reference properties (and fields), the default is `null`, thus why you ran into a `NullReferenceException`.

A similar problem for,

```
AnswerObjectCollection answer = new AnswerObjectCollection();
answer.AddRange(GetAnswersByQuestion(currQuestion.QuestionIdentity));
```

here you are just creating a separate variable, not related to the property `Answers` of class `Question`. Thus, when you do this,

```
currQuestion.Answers.AddRange(answer);
```

you run into the same issue as before.

Both can be fixed by initialization the property in the constructor.